# Berkeley DB Java Edition : Environment creation struggle

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

I'm new to Berkeley DB Java Ed. and I'm trying to use it. I have a really simple question. I can't create the Environment for the database. I'm using this code :

```
EnvironmentConfig envConf = new EnvironmentConfig();
envConf.setAllowCreate(true);
myEnv = new Environment(new File("dbEnv"), envConf);
```

Even though i've used EnvironmentConfig.setAllowConfig(true), it won't create the needed files :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment home dbEnv doesn't exist
```

I really don't get it :(
Any ideas on how to make it create the DB ? Anything else you need to know about my setup ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It will fail if the BDB log directory (in your case the dbEnv dir) is not created in advance.